# Lasso acts differently for a large (1mi obs) sample?

Tags: r, survival, lasso, glmnet

I am fitting Lasso using the glmnet package in R. 
The data contains 1 million observations and 1500 predictors. 
We have a survival outcome (time to death)

```
y_primary=cbind(data$mortality, data$death)
colnames(y_primary)=c("time","status")
x_covariates = subset(data, select=-c(mortality, death)))
x_covariate = model.matrix(~., x_covariates)

cvfit = cv.glmnet(x_covariate, y_primary, family="cox")
```

As the dataset is big, we fitted Lasso to 10,000 obs (randomly selected from the 1 million obs) first, and obtained a plot as below.

[image]

Then, when we fitted it to 20,000 obs (again, randomly selected from the 1 million obs), we obtained a plot like

[image]

The problem was, when we fitted it to the full data (1 million obs), and obtained a very awkward plot as below:

[image]

Obviously, something is not correct -- error bars are going crazy. Does anyone have an idea why we are getting such a different plot from the full data or what I can look at to troubleshoot? Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to CV! Did you try different seeds for $n = 10.000$ and $n = 20.000$, or how about an intermediate number like $n=100.000$? Can you try and reproduce this with simulated data, or attach your data? Without a MWE, we cannot reproduce your problem, so it is hardly possible to troubleshoot.